# REGEX to mask all characters except the first and last character

Tags: php, regex

I want to mask all the characters of a string except the first and last character. I tried something like this:

```
<?php
$count = 0;
$string='asdfbASDF1234';
echo preg_replace('/(?!^)\S/', '*', $string, -1 , $count);
?>
```

It is masking all characters except the first one. What is the proper regex for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the regex you want:

```
$string='asdfbASDF1234';
echo $string."\n";
echo preg_replace('/(?!^.?).(?!.{0}$)/', '*', $string);
```

Comment: This answer is marked as correct because its related to the question directly. But the alternate answer provided by Denis is also a good option.

Comment: This way it replaces all but first to me, like this: /(?!^.?).(?!.?$)/ keeps the last one

Answer (score 7):

Why not use `str_repeat()`?

```
$length = strlen($in); 
$out = $in[0] . str_repeat('*', $length - 2) . $in[$length-1];
```

Comment: +1 Several hundred times faster than mine, given a long enough string.

Comment: make sure that the len should be at least 2 character. @denis

Answer (score -2):

anyone looking for masking all letters but first of every word in given sentence:

```
   function maskele($in){
$kelimeler=explode(" ",$in);
$isim=null;
foreach ($kelimeler as $kelime){
$length = strlen($kelime);
$out = $kelime[0] . str_repeat('*', $length - 1) ; 
$isim.=$out. " ";
}
return $isim;

}
```

Comment: This is not what the question was asking, this is what the question already had and **did not want**.