# javascript replace first/last letter and enclose middle text into tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have these divs:

```
<div>lorem</div>
<div>ipsum</div>
<div>dolor</div>
```

I want to replace all the first and the last letters with another character "*"
and enclose the remaining text (in the middle) into a bold tag, like this:

```
<div>*<b>ore</b>*</div>
<div>*<b>psu</b>*</div>
<div>*<b>olo</b>*</div>
```

For the first and last letters I am using this:

```
$('div').each(function(){
    var thisTeXt = $(this).html();
    thisTeXt = thisTeXt.replace(/(^.)|(.)$/gm,'<b>*</b>');
    $(this).html(thisTeXt);
});
```

But I don't know how to enclose the middle text into the bold tags..

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/65h5cf95/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167211/regex-to-mask-all-characters-except-the-first-and-last-character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to capture the characters between the two end characters. A replace regex like this will capture those characters into the `$1` variable.

```
replace(/^.(.*).$/m, '*<b>$1</b>*')
```

**Working Example:**

```js
$('div').each(function(){
    var thisTeXt = $(this).html();
    thisTeXt = thisTeXt.replace(/^.(.*).$/m, '*<b>$1</b>*');
    $(this).html(thisTeXt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>ipsum</div>
<div>dolor</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a capture group to copy the middle into the replacement:

```
thisText = thisText.replace(/^.(.*).$/, '*<b>$1</b>*');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `html` method to change the content, that's easier than using the `each` method.

There is no need for a regular expression for simple string manipulation, you can use the `substr` method to get the content except the first and last letter, then just add `*<b>` before it and `</b>*` after it:

```
$('div').html(function(i, html){
  return '*<b>' + html.substr(1, html.length - 2) + '</b>*';
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/65h5cf95/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('div').each(function(){
    var thisTeXt = $(this).html();
    thisTeXt = thisTeXt
                       .replace(/(^.)/gm,'*<b>')
                       .replace(/(.)$/gm, '</b>*');
    $(this).html(thisTeXt);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY (without regex)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div').each(function(){
    var thisTeXt = $(this).html();
    thisTeXt =thisTeXt.replaceAt(0,'*');
    thisTeXt =thisTeXt.replaceAt(thisTeXt.length-1,'*');

    $(this).html(thisTeXt);
});
}); 
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) {
    character="<b>"+character+"</b>";
    return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+1);
 }
```

[**`Fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/emqc821L/2/)

`replaceAt` Function was taken from: [How do I replace a character at a particular index in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript) , But is modified to make your example work with `<b>*</b>`

Comment: The bold tags should be around the text between the asterisks, not around the asterisks.